# Testing '**' route in angular

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-router

I am writing a unit test to make sure that a non-registered route take the user to PageNotFoundComponent. I am not sure how to test this in a jasmine test. I am new to angular so apologize if it is a silly question.

Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish

```
it('should show page not found when route is not defined', () => {
    router.navigate(['/not-a-route']).then(() => {
       //TODO test this works as expected
       //{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
    });
});
```